# Animate div if page is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to animate my header if the page is scrolled down (lets say 300px).

How can i realize this in jquery?

Something like :

```
if (scrolled > 300px) {
$('.mydiv').slideUp();
}
else (scrolled < 300px) {
$('.mydiv').slideDown();
 }
```

thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 300 ) {
        $('.mydiv').slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.mydiv').slideDown();
    }
});
```